# Expression which should be real-valued appears to be complex-valued

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot the answer of the following integral:

```
Λ = 10;
Ω = 10;
t = 1;
Integrate[ω E^(-ω/Λ) Sin[(ω + Ω)t/2]^2/(ω + Ω)^2, {ω , 0, ∞}]
```

The answer of *Mathematica* is:

> ```
> -(1/4) E ((10 + I) π + 
>   4 ExpIntegralEi[-1] - (1 - 10 I) ExpIntegralEi[-1 + 10 I] + 
>     Gamma[0, 1 - 10 I] + (2 + 10 I) Gamma[0, 1 + 10 I]) - Sin[5]^2
> ```

The problem is that the solution of the integral involves complex functions! This is strange because the system is a physical system, so the integrand doesn't involve any complex numbers. How can I plot the answer in real space?

Comment: Please show 1. the exact code you used, 2. the output Mathematica gave,  3. and a set of real-valued parameters which, when substituted into the output, give a numerical answer with a nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: The answer is a real number.  If I apply `N` or `N[#,30]&` to it, I get an imaginary part closer to zero than the expected numerical errors.  Use `Chop` to get rid of it.  Or alternatively, knowing that the answer is real anyway, just use `Re` before plotting.

Comment: I don't think this is the exact Mathematica input you used.  `e` should be `E` instead to get this output.  In the future, please include the *exact* input you used.  Many of the problems people ask about here are exactly due to these kinds of mistakes (say, `e` instead of `E` with `e` possibly having a value ...)

Comment: @Szabolcs I Included 1- the exact code I used 2- the mathematica answer 3- the real-valued parameters in the beginning of the code.

Comment: @Szabolcs If the answer is a real number, why it gives an imaginary part?

Comment: There are many such cases, read for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Answer (score 2):

```
Λ = 10;
Ω = 10;
k[t_] := k[t] = NIntegrate[ω E^(-ω/Λ) Sin[(ω + Ω) t/2]^2/(ω + Ω)^2, {ω, 0, ∞}]

Plot[k@t, {t, 0.01, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
Λ = 10;
Ω = 10;
t = 1;

expr = Integrate[ω E^(-ω/Λ) Sin[(ω + \
Ω) t/2]^2/(ω + Ω)^2, {ω, 
   0, ∞}]

(*  Cos[10]/2 - (1/4)*E*((10 + I)*Pi + 
        4*ExpIntegralEi[-1] - 
        (1 - 10*I)*ExpIntegralEi[
            -1 + 10*I] + Gamma[0, 
          1 - 10*I] + (2 + 10*I)*
          Gamma[0, 1 + 10*I])  *)

expr // N // InputForm

(*  0.5919207759524217 - 
 5.658560762578879*^-17*I  *)
```

As stated in the comments, either [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) or [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re.html) can be used to remove the imaginary artifact.

A simpler and more accurate form can be found with [`FunctionExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html)

```
expr2 = expr // FunctionExpand // Simplify

(*  (1/2)*(Cos[10] + 
      E*(-10*Pi - 2*ExpIntegralEi[
               -1] + (1 + 5*I)*
             ExpIntegralEi[-1 - 10*I] + 
           (1 - 5*I)*ExpIntegralEi[
               -1 + 10*I]))  *)

expr2 // N // InputForm

(*  0.591920775952417 + 0.*I  *)
```

The real part is the same and the imaginary part is now zero within machine precision.

The integral can be done analytically for arbitrary real t

```
Clear[t]

expr3 = Assuming[{Element[t, Reals]}, Integrate[
    ω E^(-ω/Λ) Sin[(ω + Ω) \
t/2]^2/(ω + Ω)^2,
    {ω, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify]

(*  ((1/4)*(E^(20*I*t) + E^(1 + 10*I*t)*
           (EulerGamma - 10*I*t + 
              10*I*EulerGamma*t - 
              20*t*ArcTan[10*t] + 
              CoshIntegral[-1 - 10*I*t] + 
              2*(1 - 5*I*t)*CoshIntegral[
                  -1 + 10*I*t] - 
              4*ExpIntegralEi[-1] - 
              Log[-1 - 10*I*t] + 
              2*Log[1 - 10*I*t] + 
              2*(-1 + 5*I*t)*
                Log[-1 + 10*I*t] + 
              2*Log[1 + 10*I*t] + 
              2*(-1 + 5*I*t)*SinhIntegral[
                  1 - 10*I*t] - SinhIntegral[
                1 + 10*I*t]) + (-1 - 10*I*t)*
           Derivative[1, 0, 0][
               Hypergeometric1F1][2, 2, 
             1 + 10*I*t]))/E^(10*I*t)  *)

FullSimplify[expr3 /. t -> 1] // N // InputForm

(*  0.5919207759524197 + 0.*I  *)

Plot[expr3, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

A simpler form can be obtained for positive t

```
expr4 = Assuming[{t > 0},
  Integrate[
    ω E^(-ω/Λ) Sin[(ω + Ω) \
t/2]^2/(ω + Ω)^2,
    {ω, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify]

(*  (1/4)*(E*(2*EulerGamma - I*Pi - 
           20*t*ArcTan[10*t] + 
           CoshIntegral[-1 - 10*I*t] - 
           4*ExpIntegralEi[-1] + 
           ExpIntegralEi[-1 + 10*I*t] + 
           Log[-1 + 10*I*t] + 
           Log[1 + 10*I*t] - SinhIntegral[
             1 + 10*I*t]) + I*E^(10*I*t)*
        (I + 10*t)*Derivative[1, 0, 0][
            Hypergeometric1F1][2, 2, 
          1 - 10*I*t] + 
      ((-1 - 10*I*t)*
           Derivative[1, 0, 0][
               Hypergeometric1F1][2, 2, 
             1 + 10*I*t])/E^(10*I*t))  *)

(expr4 /. t -> 1) // N // InputForm

(*  0.591920775952417 + 0.*I  *)

Plot[expr4, {t, -1, 1}]
```

[image]